# How to disable the Bitnami banner?

Tags: magento2, google-cloud

I've installed the Bitnami Certified Magento on GCP. How do you disable the bitnami banner that appears in the bottom right hand of the home page? The [instructions referenced on the page from the banner](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/bitnami-remove-banner/) is to run:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/bnconfig --disable_banner 1`

The result is:

`sudo: /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try this : -

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig –disable_banner YES
check your site.
```

Update :-

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig.disabled --disable_banner 1
```

And more :-

**https://shaileshthedeveloper.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/remove-bitnami-banner-from-magneto2/**

**https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-disable-bitnami-banner-on-magento-homepage/77519**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Thanks, but yeah I still get ```sudo: /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig: command not found``` for ```sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig –disable_banner YES```

Comment: i think permission issues.you apply permission

Comment: Maybe, but there isn't a bnconfig file under /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig, just a /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig.disabled file.

Comment: yes found that same issues check this links --- https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-disable-bitnami-banner-on-magento-homepage/77519

Comment: run this command and check `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig.disabled --disable_banner 1`

Comment: Excellent. That worked! Thank you. Do you need to updated your answer above for me to mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @Christo check update...